# Splitting a string into multiple strings after a specified character in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to create a script that takes in a string with an unknown number of parts that are separated by `';'`.

```
"blah blah one; blah blah two"
```

I tried to use the (?: re) example from [rubydocs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UJ) but had no luck with it. Can someone show me the best way to do this?

Comment: Nobody can know what your talking about without significan sample data. And thats a fact Jack!

Comment: The example I gave is exactly like the data I plan to receive. 
String0 = "anything pretty much; anything else prety much; maybe something else"

and then make String0 into however many parts there are with the ; as the cut point ex: 
String1 = "anything pretty much"
String2 = "anything else prety much"
String3 = "maybe something else"

hope that helps

Comment: So, let me get this straight dude. You want to find the strpos() where every `;` is?

Comment: And regex blah blah blah is your solution...

Comment: Im sorry the example was not explicit enough for you. I am honestly just wanting to split a string into parts after a semicolon. I will try to be more specific in the future. Thank you for you question critique.

Comment: Hey, nice try. Unfortunately things come possibly before and after a semicolon that split may have problems with, but hey, each to his own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just use the split method

```
a='blah blah blah;blah foo blah'.split(";")
```

the parts will be store in index from 0 to 1 (in the above example )